# The notification of when I applied for a job doesn't take my timezone into acount

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, jobs, timezone

I just applied for a position on careers.stackoverflow.com
The confirmation message is currently telling me I applied Feb. 1st However where I am that is actually Tomorrow.

Here's a screeenshot of what I'm talking about.
[image: screenshot highlighting local time and applied time]

Comment: How can this be a bug if you never filled any time zone? The server can't and should not guess your time zone. All time related stuff in Stack Exchange are UTC.

Comment: Shouldn't be too hard to do using Javascript...

Comment: @ShadowWizard - If it can't provide a data reliably, then it shouldn't try, in my opinion. If a dates not happening, then I don't see what's wrong with "3 days ago", as on posts and the like.

Comment: @Chris  fair enough, worth raising as feature request - as it stands, most likely as a bug this would be just marked [tag:status-bydesign]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this. There are a few gotchas with a simple JavaScript approach.

First, whatever approach we adopt, we'll want to support it consistently across the site. That includes for webcrawler requests, meaning we'll still have to render a UTC date anyway. Layering JS on top of that will effect something similar to [FOUC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content).

Second, the JS approach depends on the browser DOM and ultimately on the user's OS time zone. This has a habit of changing for users who travel a lot, which can lead to dates on the site that appear to change. Ultimately, we'd want to support explicit user preference (as we do with our language code, which looks at the Accept-Language header but can be overridden by user preference).

For now, we consider the reported behavior to be by-design, but we'll keep a look out for situations in which time rendering is confusing and re-evaluate the design as needed.